# Far Manager plugin that support quickly jumping to directories

Tags: windows, file-management, far-manager

When in Linux, I use fzf and jump to achieve quickly directory navigation. This is quite productive.

Is there a solution for the [Far Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Manager)?

Answer (score 1):

Go

Menu "Commands"- "Folder shortcuts" - hotkey for folder navigation, Ctrl+T for view directory trees.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wting/autojump/

AutoJump, it's a Python program and will help you move fast between directories in command line. Has a Windows Explorer extension too. I'm sure it can be integrated into Far Manager too.